# SQL Server query hierarchical results using a CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an `emp` table like this:

[image]

I need to group by `DeptNo` and `JOB`.

I am using the following code to generate group by

```
;With Cte as
(
    select 
        DeptNo, Count(EMPNO) Total 
    from 
        Emp 
    group by 
        DeptNo

    union all 

    select  
        DeptNo, Count(EMPNO) Total 
    from 
        Emp 
    group by 
        DeptNo, Job 
) 
select * 
from Cte 
order by DeptNo, Total desc
```

But I need to make the output as below

[image]

Is there any option to generate similar results in SQL with dynamic CTE?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT x.DeptNo AS [Dept/Job], COUNT(*) AS Cnt, x.DeptNo, 1 AS RowType
FROM dbo.emp x
GROUP BY x.DepNo

UNION ALL 

SELECT y.Job, COUNT(*), y.DepNo, 2 AS RowType
FROM dbo.emp y
GROUP BY y.Job, y.DepNo

ORDER BY DepNo, RowType
```